# Change datepicker format and save to database in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a log_leave table like below

```
    id |  name   | request_day_leave | start_leave | end_leave
     1   Michael            5          2019-04-01    2019-04-05
     2   Johan              3          2019-04-08    2019-04-011
```

I want to change datepicker show in blade view form, so when the user click date, it shows dd-mm-yy. And when user see log report, it shows like below

```
     id |  name   | request_day_leave | Leave Start | Leave End
     1   Michael            5           01-04-2019    05-04-2019
     2   Johan              3           08-04-2019    11-04-2019
```

I have changed datepicker format in form blade view, but when I need to save the date to database, it's showing error message like below

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '08-04-2019' for column 'from_date' at row 1
```

I've tried using mutator in the model, and added a new value into config/app.php but it's still got the same error message

Here's the config/app code

```
'date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
'date_format_js' => 'dd/mm/yy'
```

Here's datepicker code

```
 $('#from').datepicker({
    showOnFocus: false,
    showTrigger: '#calImg',
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
 });
    $('#to').datepicker({
        showOnFocus: false,
        showTrigger: '#calImg',
        beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
        pickerClass: 'noPrevNext',
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
 });
});
```

Here's the code in Log Leave model

```
class LogLeave extends Model
{
//
protected $table = 'log_leave';

public function setEntryDateAttribute($input)
{
    $this->attributes['start_leave'] = 
    Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format'), $input)->format('dd-mm-yy');
    $this->attributes['end_leave'] = 
    Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format'), $input)->format('dd-mm-yy');
}
```

}

How to fix this issue ?

Thank you

Comment: Hello, MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format, so before inserting in DB, format the same in required manner.

Comment: Hi @SonamTripathi, yeah, what I want is when user view log leave in form view, in start date and end date it shows in d-m-y format instead of basic database format (y-m-d)

Comment: Yeah, I understood your concern. You need to not to change format in view , just do the same once form get submitted in PHP side.

Comment: Hi, yeah, thank you for your suggestion, I think in the database the format will be default, all I need is change format when in view blade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think again format() is not required

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$input);
```

or

```
Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format'), $input);
```

Comment: I think you are getting input as string so you might be getting this error 

$date = strtotime($input); 
Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format'), date('d/m/Y', $date));

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the format to yyyy-mm-dd when storing in database

```
public function setEntryDateAttribute($input)
{
    $this->attributes['start_leave'] = 
    Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format'), $input)->format('Y-m-d');
    //should be format('Y-m-d') not format('dd-mm-yy')

    $this->attributes['end_leave'] = 
    Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format'), $input)->format('Y-m-d');
    //same applies here
}
```

And then use accessors to format the value to dd-mm-yyyy format

```
public function getStartLeaveAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y');
}

public function getEndLeaveAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y');
}
```